# Multiple PouchDB instance assigns to object using node.js

Tags: node.js, pouchdb

I have multiple databases and I want to connect all databases in Node.js when my app initialize

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
exports.connectDB = (files) => {
  let db = {};
  let options = {};

  files.forEach((file, i) => {
    db[file.name] = new PouchDB(file.path, options);
    if (files.length === i + 1) {
      return db;
    }
  });
}
```

It's returning **db** as undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning db instance from function that is used in `forEach` not from `connectDB`. Could you try this:

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
exports.connectDB = (files) => {
  let db = {};
  let options = {};

  files.forEach((file, i) => {
    db[file.name] = new PouchDB(file.path, options);
  });

  return db;
}
```

This way when all files are processed, `db` object will be returned from `connectDB`function.